# How can I highlight Python function calls with in VS Code?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I would like to know how to enable the highlighting of function call in VS Code with python. See the following example where function call is blank, as other part of the code:

[image]

Comment: Did you turn it off ever?

Comment: Try restarting the language server.  Open the command pallete and search for "restart language server" for python.

Comment: Okay it was just about the theme that I was using ( Atom one dark theme ) that was not highlightning the function call. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the colour theme you are using isn't highlighting things in the way you want. [You can change that](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/themes#_customizing-a-color-theme). (see the `Developer: Inspect Editor Tokens and Scopes` command in the command palette) Ex.

[Semantic highlighting customization](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/semantic-highlight-guide#theming) route (requires a language extension that provides semantic highlighting support for Python) (highlights both function definitions and calls):

```json
"editor.semanticTokenColorCustomizations": {
    "[Theme Name Goes Here]": { // remove this wrapper to apply to all themes
        "rules": {
            "function:python": { // remove ":python" to apply to all languages
                "foreground": "#FF0000", // TODO
                // "fontStyle": "" // optional
            }
        }   
    }
}
```

^the `:python` part will make the colour customization only apply to functions for the Python language.

If you want the call for function declarations to be different, then write another similar rule, but use the `declaration` modifier. Ex. `function.declaration:python`.

---

Token colour customization route (works without any extensions, since [VS Code bundles TextMate grammar support for Python](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/tree/main/extensions/python/syntaxes)) (may require *disabling* extensions that provide semantic highlighting support for Python):

```json
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
    "[Theme Name Goes Here]": { // remove this wrapper to apply to all themes
        "textMateRules": [
            {
                "scope": "meta.function-call.python",
                "settings": {
                    "foreground": "#FF0000", // TODO
                    // "fontStyle": "" // optional
                }
            }
        ]
    }
},
```

See also the scopes `support.function.builtin.python`, `meta.function-call.generic.python`, and `meta.member.access.python, meta.function-call.python`.

Answer (score 0):

Okay it was just about the theme that I was using ( Atom one dark theme ) that was not highlightning the function call. I switched to another one and it's now working.